# Multiple Common Fields CreatedOn and CreatedBy in every table of a database. How it can be without repeating for every table

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-core-mvc

Scenerio:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy {get; set; }
}

public class TestItem
{
    public int TestItemId { get; set; }
    public string TestItemName { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy {get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy {get; set; }
}
```

the problem is that, every time I create a table I have to add those two columns repeatedly.

But I want like this-

```
public class EntryLog
{
   public int EntryLogId { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set; }
   public string CreatedBy {get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public EntryLog EntryLog { get; set; }
    public int EntryLogId { get; set; }
}

and so on...

class A { .. }

class B { .. }
```

But its creating problem [showing conflicts error with other table's foreign key] while creating a row for a Department or a Patient.

In EF core, there is **Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)** but in that case every table will be merged into a single table. But that doesn't give me any solution.

looking forward to expert's suggestion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom line is: use `EntryLog` as a base type and don't tell EF about it. It's easy enough to keep EF-core oblivious of the base type: only register the derived types. Doing so, EF-core will map your subtypes to their own tables, just as if they didn't have a common type.

Now `EntryLog` will no longer need an `Id`, and it should be abstract:

```
public abstract class EntryLog
{
    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Whether this is enough depends on your specific requirements. There are several possibilities.

#### 1. No additional configuration

If you're happy with the default conventions EF will apply to the common properties, your done. `CreatedOnUtc` will be mapped to a `DateTime2` column (in Sql Server) and `CreatedBy` to an `nvarchar(max)` column in each table for an `EntryLog` entity.

However, if you do need custom configurations --for example if you want to map `CreatedBy` to an `nvarchar(50)` column-- additional mapping instructions should be applied. And of course you still want to do the mapping of the common properties only once --which would also happen if you *did* map the base type in a TPH scheme. How to do that?

#### 2. Data annotations in the base type

The easiest option is to add data annotations:

```
public abstract class EntryLog
{
    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And that's all.

But there are dev teams that don't want to use data annotations for mapping instructions. Also, EF's fluent mappings offer more options than data annotations do. If data annotations don't fit the bill for whatever reason, fluent configurations must be applied. But still, you only want to configure the common properties only once. A viable way to achieve that is to use [`IEntityTypeConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ientitytypeconfiguration-1)s for each `EntryLog` and let each concrete configuration derive from a base class. This offers two more options.

#### 3. The base class contains regular properties

Option 4 will make clear why I talk about "regular properties" here. This is what it looks like:

```
abstract class EntryLogConfiguration
{
    public void ConfigureBase<TEntity>(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : EntryLog
    {
        // Just an example of how to configure a base property.
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}

class DepartmentConfiguration : EntryLogConfiguration, 
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Department>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Department> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.DepartmentName).HasMaxLength(100);
        ConfigureBase(builder);
    }
}
```

And in the context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DepartmentConfiguration());
}
```

#### 4. Using shadow properties

[Shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) is a new feature of EF-core.

> Shadow properties are properties that are not defined in your .NET entity class but are defined for that entity type in the EF Core model. The value and state of these properties is maintained purely in the Change Tracker.

Let's suppose you want to have `CreatedBy` as a class property (because you want to show it in a UI) but only need `CreatedOnUtc` as a property that's set in the background and that shouldn't be exposed. Now `EntryLog` will look like this:

```
public abstract class EntryLog
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

So the property `CreatedOnUtc` is gone. It has been moved to the base configuration as shadow property:

```
abstract class EntryLogConfiguration
{
    public void ConfigureBase<TEntity>(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : EntryLog
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property<DateTime>("CreatedOnUtc");
    }
}
```

Now you can't set `CreatedOnUtc` directly, only through EF's change tracker. The best place to do that is in an override of `SaveChanges` in the context:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<EntryLog>())
        {
            entry.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedOnUtc").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Of course, if `UpdatedOnUtc` was a regular property, this override would also come in handy, but you could just do

```
            entry.Entity.CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

I hope this will give you enough food for thought to figure out which option suits you best.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Gert Arnold for your nice explanation. I've solved the problem according to your detailed reply.

Comment: I also typically use a base class for these scenarios, works perfectly. I also like to actually hide entity framework information from my business logic altogether. My business model defines its state through an interface and this is injected into it with a specific implementation. Now my business model doesn't know if it is EFCore, MongoDb, an in-memory dictionary or whatever that is providing its state.